# Node js API returning empty data while console prints correct data

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

This is strange. I have created a nodejs api which does some heavy processing of the data and returns the response. The problem with this API is, its returning the empty data but when I do console, it shows correct data. I am completely unsure why node is behaving like this to me.

Here is my code (relevant code):

## app.js

```
app.post('/abc/cdeApi', (request, response) => {
    myController.cdeApi(request, response)
})
```

## myController.js

```
    cdeApi(request, response){
            this.simpleHttpRequestHandler(request, response);
        }

simpleHttpRequestHandler(request, response){
         return (async () =>{
                console.log("Inside base controller")
                let result = await this.myService.cdeApi(request.body);
                console.log(result); // It prints correct here...
                response.status(200).json({result}); // But result goes an empty array
            }
        })();
    }
```

## myService.js

```
cdeApi(body){
return (async() => {
  console.log("Inside Service")
  let rawResponse = this.myQueryHelper.cdeApi(body); // Received the raw response from DB
  let processedResponse = this.processResponse(rawResponse);
})
}

processResponse(response){
 let finalData = [] ; // I believe its returning this only, without waiting for loop below to complete
 for(i =0; i<=rawData.length; i++){
  finalData[rawData.id] = rawData.data;

 }
console.log(finalData); // Prints conrrect value
 return finalData; // return empty (initialized) value.
}
```

Comment: are you using mode: "no-cors"

Comment: sending response from somewhere else,
It will be helpful if you can also mention response code

Comment: In myController.js I have mentioned " response.status(200).json({result});"
You looking for anything else?

Comment: @rahulmr No.. .

Answer (score 0):

```
response.status(200).json({result});
```

should be
    response.status(200).json(result);

Comment: nope if her wants his result to look like this :
`{ 
   results: [...]
}`
this is valid

Comment: yes.. I want output as json object everytime.. so I guess thats valid

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way in your controller

```
async function simpleHttpRequestHandler(request, response){

     console.log("Inside base controller")
     let result = await this.myService.cdeApi(request.body);
     console.log(result); 
     response.status(200).json({result}); 
}
```

also i doubt that possibly somewhere in your code, there is an empty `next()` call

Comment: yeah, apologize, fixed that though. Did it help?

Comment: No :( .. still this is having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so the question was due to a silly mistake. Here is the sample code with the issue (in myService.js):

```
processResponse(response){
 let finalData = [] ; // This needed to be initialized as an object
 for(i =0; i<=rawData.length; i++){
  finalData[rawData.id] = rawData.data;

 }
```

I have intialized finalData as an array, but while looping through I am treating finalData variable as an object. Remember JS doesn't have datatype. So in this case, JS is treating both as different variable and its returning finalData (which was initialized to an array)